# jQuery set focus on selected item of a select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I have a select list that is `size="10"` - so it always shows 10 of the 100 options available.

When the page loads, the 1st 10 options are always displayed, even if option value 50 is `selected`.

I have read that adding `focus` to the selected item of the select list will work so that when the page loads option 50 will be displayed in the select list, instead of the 1st 10 options.

However, after reading many threads and searching google, I am unable to work out how to set the `focus` to the selected item.

I am wanting to set **both** the `selected` and the `focus` applied to the item of the select list.

Here is what I have tried and does not work:

```
$('#id_preview_style_select option:selected').prop('selected', true);  //set the selected value.

$('#id_preview_style_select option:selected').prop('focus', true);  //does not work.
$('#id_preview_style_select option:selected').focus();  //does not work
```

This is what I am seeking to achieve:

```
<select id="id_preview_style_select" size="10" autofocus>
  <option value="0">Style 0</option>
  <option value="1">Style 1</option>
  <option value="2">Style 2</option>
  <option value="3">Style 3</option>
  ....
  <option value="50" selected focus>Style 50</option>
  ....
  <option value="99">Style 99</option>
  <option value="100">Style 100</option>
</select>
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: `<option>` tag doesn't support most events and can't be hidden either in some browsers. Suggest you look for a plugin that modifies select and is therefore customizable. Numerous ones available since `<select>` is  a difficult tag to work with

Answer (score 0):

`.prop('focus', true);` would never work since `focus()` is a method, not a property (need to be invoked).

Try `$('#id_preview_style_select option:selected').focus();`

If it doesn't work right away you might need to `timeout` it with a timeout of 0 milliseconds. Hopefully that will help.

Edit: if none of this works (it might be that browsers would not allow this) I'd just scroll the list of options, so user can see what is selected.

Comment: Pawel, how do i use the timeout with the .focus()?

Comment: `setTimeout( function(){ YOUR_CODE_HERE }, 0);` - 0 is a parameter for time. Basically it's a trick that makes all Javascript run, then run this piece of code. Depending of your implementation there is a small chance this would help. But as @charlietfl mentioned - it might be forbidden to set focus on a option element.